# A word/phrase/idiom for 'going & coming back'

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

In my mother tongue, there is a word that describes the entire event of...

> your *going to one place and coming back.*

The beauty of this word is it is very useful as in **one word**, you describe the entire thing **and** with **a bit of negation**!

Let's build an example:

> I want to have a driving license *(InE)* ~ Oh, that's not an easy task with local RTO (Regional Transport Office). You'll have minimum ***[the word in my mother tongue].***

If I say, you'll have to visit the RTO thrice, it works but then the word 'visit' has no negation in it.

Few more examples:

> Did you go to her place? ~ Yes, I did/had three ***[the word in my mother tongue]*** (i.e. comings and goings), but she did not seem to be interested in the project.

The closest word that comes to my mind is the word ***'visit'***.

I'm asking natives; do you use 'visits' for the following example?

> My 'visit' to the place was a waste 
>  You'll have to have several 'visits' to get the work done 
>  I wasted my time for the 'failed visits' I made.

Or there is another word/phrase/idiom to pass a clear message? Please mind the *negation*.

Note: I know the use of 'have been' for the places but that's not I'm looking for. Typically, the word I'm searching for is a 'noun' as in my second-last example.

Comment: Your use of *visit* is perfectly fine. *I will have to visit the dentist three times to get my dental work done.* The fact that you're not there now implies that it is no longer the case, which is the negation I think you're looking for..

Comment: @Catija no, three visits are *required* to do the work. They are genuine visits. Here, I'm talking about the apathy government officers show or for that sake, for silly reasons/ignorance or whatever, you will have to make several visits. Check the last three examples of mine.

Comment: There's no difference between them... at least not in English.  You could always just use *go*... *I had to go to the grocery store three times before I finally remembered to buy the toilet paper*.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean by "negation".  Is it *just* to indicate that the visits are required and there is no way to avoid them?  Or are you specifically trying to imply that the visits are unpleasant?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm probably wrong but I'd assumed that when he said "negation", he meant that the trip was over.  You're right that he could easily mean negative connotation.

Comment: If there's a word in your native tongue that means "visit where you get nothing accomplished", it probably isn't translatable into one word in English (although I can see how it would be useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term that comes closest to what you're looking for is either **trips** or **round trips.**

A **trip** is a journey. A **round trip** is a journey that starts and ends in the same place. So if you start at home, travel to Paris, and then come back home, you have made a **round trip** to Paris.

In many cases, the "round" nature of a trip is implied. So the most common way of expressing what you're talking about would be:

> You want to get a driving license? Oh, that's a pain. You'll have to make at least three trips.

The idea of multiple trips already, depending on context, carries some mild sense that the trips are a burden. If you use "round trips" instead, it emphasizes this:

> You want to get a driving license? Oh, that's a pain. You'll have to make at least three round trips.

As best I can tell, this is the most idiomatic way to express what you're looking to express.

Answer (score 0):

A good word that means "involved event that will take a long time that you would prefer not to do" would be *ordeal*.

I think what you'd be trying to say with *minimum* in that sentence would be expressed with "at least a little bit of."

> I want to have a driving license (InE) ~ Oh, that's not an easy task with local RTO (Regional Transport Office). It'll be at least a little bit of an ordeal.

English doesn't have a common single word that I know of for something like "bad" or "unsuccessful" visit, or "visit where you tried." -

Well now that I think about it - *try* or *attempt* might work - if the visit was meant to accomplish something.

> I wasted my time for the failed tries I made.

That's the thing - *visit* just means you are going to a place, not necessarily that you are doing something there.

If you mean something like "visit where the work is not complete," use the word *session*, or *appointment* if it's something like a doctor or other professional.

> You'll have to have several *sessions* to get the work done
>
> You'll have to have several *appointments* to get the work done

Both of these would be inappropriate in family or settings where you aren't seeing a professional for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If a single trip (or a continuing series of trips) includes obtaining something, or retrieving something, you can use the word **fetching**.  For example:

> Jack and Jill went up the hill,
>   to fetch a pail of water.

or

> Jack fetched a pail of water.

In a context where water is at the top of the hill, the second example implies that Jack went up the hill, either half-filled a pail with water or obtained an already half-full pail, and brought the half-full pail back down the hill.

"Fetch" is an old-fashioned word, but is known by almost all native speakers of English. (Mostly because of the nursery rhyme, but also because it is a standard command in dog-training.)

Because "fetch" is a standard command in dog-training, it does have a "familiar" or "condescending" connotation when used to discuss something a person does.  Here are some examples:

> Red played fetch with Rover.
>   Let me fetch that for you.
>   [Farmboy, fetch me that pitcher.](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003784/quotes)

Also, the word "fetching" is a quaint adjective used to describe something that attracts men to women.  For example:

> That is a very fetching dress.